# Unsure as to why tkinter buttons aren't resizing correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create an interactable grid of buttons that acts as a board for a game. The user inputs the `rowCount` and `colCount` and `create_board` creates a grid of buttons of the specified dimensions. I would like the buttons to take up the entire frame and expand with window resizing. I'm not sure why my grid of buttons only expands vertically or why they're anchored to the left side of the window, despite specifying the sticky for the buttons to be set to `nsew`.

```
class BoardWindow(tk.Tk, Engine):

    def __init__(self, colCount, rowCount, numPlayers, playerList, iconList):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.engine = Engine()

        self.boardFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.boardFrame.pack(expand = True, fill = "both")

        self.create_board(colCount, rowCount)


    def create_board(self, colCount, rowCount):

        for rowIndex in range(rowCount):
            tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self.boardFrame, rowIndex, weight = 1)

            for colIndex in range(colCount):
                tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.boardFrame, colCount, weight=1)
                newButton = tk.Button(self.boardFrame, command=lambda: 
                                      self.engine.updateBoard(rowIndex, colIndex))
                newButton.grid(row=rowIndex, column= colIndex, sticky="nsew")
```

[image: Pic of 3x3 grid window at default size]

[image: Pic of 3x3 grid window when fullscreened]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is quite simple: you wrote

```
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.boardFrame, colCount, weight=1)
```

so only the column after the last column containing buttons expands (column number `colCount`). What you wanted to write was

```
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self.boardFrame, colIndex, weight=1)
```

with `colIndex`.

By the way, you can configure the columns/rows directly with

```
self.boardFrame.columnconfigure(colIndex, weight=1)
self.boardFrame.rowconfigure(rowIndex, weight=1)
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!